# Saving data from SQL query in excel in C# console app

Tags: c#, sql, excel, c#-4.0

I have a c# program.cs code which is created to save results from sql query to xls file, the problem is that I have two sql query and there are two result sets which need to written to the excel file, I am able to write the 1st result through the below code but not able to write the second result, can you please help on this? Please see my code below, I am using same code block for both the queries but always seem to get results from 1st query.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     //SqlConnection cnn;
     //string connectionstring = null;
     string connectionstring = "Integrated Security = SSPI;Initial Catalog=Database; Data Source=<Instance Name>;";
     string sql1 = null;
     string sql2 = null;
     string data = null;
     string data1 = null;
     int i = 0;
     int j = 0;
     string Filename = @"E:\file\testfile.xls";
     if (!File.Exists(Filename))
     {
         File.Create(Filename).Dispose();
         using (TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(Filename))
         {
             tw.WriteLine("The very first line!");
             tw.Close();
         }
     }

     ////*** Preparing excel Application
     Excel.Application xlApp;
     Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook;
     Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet;
     object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

     ///*** Opening Excel application
     xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
     xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(Filename);
     xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)(xlWorkBook.ActiveSheet as Excel.Worksheet);

     xlApp.DisplayAlerts = false;
     SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
     //cnn = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);
     conn.Open();

     ////** Write your Sql Query here
     sql1 = "Select top 5 DocumentId, DocFileName from <table> order by CreateDate desc";
     sql2 = "Select top 5 DocID, Title from <Table> order by CreateDate desc";

     ///*** Preparing to retrieve value from the database
     SQL.DataTable dtable = new SQL.DataTable();

     SqlDataAdapter dscmd = new SqlDataAdapter(sql1, conn);
     SQL.DataSet ds = new SQL.DataSet();
     dscmd.Fill(dtable);

     ////*** Generating the column Names here
     string[] colNames = new string[dtable.Columns.Count];
     int col = 0;

     foreach (SQL.DataColumn dc in dtable.Columns)
        colNames[col++] = dc.ColumnName;

     char lastColumn = (char)(65 + dtable.Columns.Count - 1);

     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Value2 = colNames;
     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").Font.Bold = true;

     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("A1", lastColumn + "1").VerticalAlignment
                        = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

     /////*** Inserting the Column and Values into Excel file
     for (i = 0; i <= dtable.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
     {
          for (j = 0; j <= dtable.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
          {
              data = dtable.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
              xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data;
              xlWorkBook.Save();   
          }
     }

     //Enter new block in Excel -- for the second query, I need help here below

     SQL.DataTable dtable1 = new SQL.DataTable();

     SqlDataAdapter dscmd1 = new SqlDataAdapter(sql2, conn);
     SQL.DataSet ds1 = new SQL.DataSet();
     dscmd1.Fill(dtable1);

     ////*** Generating the column Names here

     string[] colNames1 = new string[dtable1.Columns.Count];
     int col1 = 0;

     foreach (SQL.DataColumn dc in dtable1.Columns)
         colNames1[col1++] = dc.ColumnName;

     char lastColumn1 = (char)(68 + dtable1.Columns.Count - 1);
     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", lastColumn1 + "1").Value2 = colNames1;
     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", lastColumn1 + "1").Font.Bold = true;
     xlWorkSheet.get_Range("D1", lastColumn1 + "1").VerticalAlignment
                        = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignCenter;

     /////*** Inserting the Column and Values into Excel file
     for (i = 0; i <= dtable1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
     {
          for (j = 0; j <= dtable1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
          {
               data1 = dtable1.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
               xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data1;
               xlWorkBook.Save();
          }
     }
     //end of block
     xlWorkBook.Close(true, misValue, misValue);
     xlApp.Quit();

     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkSheet);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkBook);
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
}
```

[Image from Excel result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xr5R.jpg)

Comment: Are you sure the second query returns any rows? Both of your declared datasets are unused and contribute to cluttered code. You could make one database call with the two queries separated by a semicolon and fill one of those datasets with the two resultant data tables to be more efficient.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your comments, I just found that both the data tables returns the column values from both the queries. but in the for loop I get only results from query 1 Any suggestions please? 
for (i = 0; i <= dtable1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
            {
                for (j = 0; j <= dtable1.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
                {
                    data1 = dtable1.Rows[i].ItemArray[j].ToString();
                    xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 2, j + 1] = data1;
                    xlWorkBook.Save();
                   }
            }

Comment: I tried to fill the dataset with the datatable, but in for loop there is no method like dtable.Column.count for datasets. I used the below-  ds.Tables.Add(dtable); @Crowcoder

Comment: Does your second query return any rows? Use the debugger to find out.

Comment: Yes, it returns 5 rows and two columns.

Comment: @Crowcoder - I think the problem lies here - xlWorkSheet.Cells[i + 5, j + 4] = data1; For the second query if I do i+5 and j+4 it writes both the result set but it leaves 3 rows blank   before writing the second query under D column.. Any idea please?

Comment: Sorry, this is not one of those problems that I can identify just by looking at your code.